# Add a Custom Field to WooCommerce Order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

**Hi, I'm trying to show a custom field made with jet-engine, in order details.**

https://prnt.sc/15joyn6

Can someone help me?

Code:

**

```
**/**
 * Display field value on the order edit page
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );
function my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta( $order ){
    $order_id = method_exists( $order, 'get_id' ) ? $order->get_id() : $order->id;
    echo '<p><strong>'.__('Teste1').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order_id, 'Teste1', true ) . '</p>';
}**
```

**

Comment: Have you tried the ID `_teste1` instead of `Teste1` in your PHP code? `Teste1` is only a label, computer code typically prefers id’s.

Comment: Hi, how are you?
Yes, I tried, both ways.